# Cleanest way to add a 'user bar' to most (but not all) of my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a 'user bar' that says 'Signed in as current_user.name' that I want to render in most (but not all) of my views.  **What is the preferred/cleanest way to implement this?**  I.e. is it an if statement in the application layout?  A partial that I render in every view where I want it to appear?

Comment: you could create a dedicated layout too. You only know whether or not it's relevant

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you have functionality in your layout template that should conditionally show up based on the view that is being seen, not just session state like is the logger signed in.  For this, you can use a [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)
in the views that allows you to set the appropriate content in the views.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second layout, and then for the actions where you *don't* want this user bar to show you would use the different layout:

```
render :layout => "not_logged_in"
```